# How do I get the average from a mysql column minus highest and lowest value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped. I want to get the average "clicks" from "posts" but throw away the highest value which typically is so high that it skews the threshold when I want to display all posts with clicks above the average. I also want to discard the lowest value for the same reason. My code is:

```
//get the sum of the clicks from all posts    

$gettotalsum = mysql_query("SELECT sum(clicks) AS click_total FROM posts WHERE clicks > '0' "); 

$clicksum = @mysql_fetch_array($gettotalsum);


//get the number of posts that have clicks                      
$postcount = mysql_query("SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE isactive = 'y' AND clicks > '0' "); 

$clickcount = mysql_num_rows($postcount);
```

I suspect that the two queries above are what I need to modify to filter highest and lowest click values - but how?

and here's the rest of my code fwiw:

```
//multiply to get the average, then round it off
$average = $clicksum['clicks'] / $clickcount;
$average = round($average); 

//display posts that are equal to or above average

$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT postid, posturl, posttitle, clicks FROM posts WHERE clicks >= $average order by clicks DESC");

    while ($aboveaverageposts = @mysql_fetch_array($getposts)) {

    //code to format output goes here

    }
```

I do suspect all this code can be streamlined, but most important right now I'm looking to filter the highest and lowest values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the average minus the highest and lowest values (as your title says) is a bit tricky.  I want this to work:

```
SELECT (sum(clicks) - max(clicks) - min(clicks)) / (count(*) - 2) as avgclicks
FROM posts
WHERE clicks > '0'
```

Unfortunately, you could have duplicate records with the largest and smallest values, so the count woud be off.  This approach should work:

```
select avg(clicks) as avgclicks
from posts p cross join
     (select max(clicks) as maxclicks, min(clicks) as minclicks
      from posts p
      where clicks > 0
     ) minmax
where clicks > minmax.minclicks and clicks < minmax.maxclicks;
```

To get everything with "above average" clicks, you can put this in a `where` clause:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where clicks > (select avg(clicks) as avgclicks
                from posts p cross join
                     (select max(clicks) as maxclicks, min(clicks) as minclicks
                      from posts
                      where clicks > 0
                     ) minmax
                where clicks > minmax.minclicks and clicks < minmax.maxclicks
               )
```

Comment: That did it! With just a few tweaks to order the results, and add other criteria to the select it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to come up with a simple algo to decide what this threshold is, and you shouldn't assume it's only 1 column.  It's better to figure out a percentage, like say any entry 5x above the average (let's assume your average is 5, so anything 25 or more is garbage, obviously tweak this to your needs)

```
SELECT AVG(clicks) AS average_click 
FROM posts 
HAVING clicks < AVG(clicks)*5
```

PS: I wrote this SQL from memory, so the syntax might not be perfect

Comment: I believe this is not correct entirely. If he has, lets say, a really big extreme value (for example, having an average of 5 and an extreme of 1,000,000), it will affect a lot the results. I believe using `STD()` (standard deviation) would be better, but he'll need to study this a little bit.